# Count MySql Data based on drop box value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I want to create a code number generator that increases 1 value based on the type of drop-down box in my **.php** file.
How it works is the user choose the type from the drop-down box as the function will count the `type`
column from the `sys` table

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sys
WHERE type = (drop down box value);
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <label for="PartType">Part Type</label></br>
  <select name="PartType" id="type">
  <option value="C">Camera</option>
  <option value="L">Lighting</option>
  <option value="X">Lens</option>
  <option value="R">Controller</option>
  <option value="B">Cable</option>
  <option value="S">Scope</option>
  </select>
  </div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
<input type="text" name="RAND" id="ivno" readonly>
</div>
```

Then it will generate a code number of `['type'] + '-' [default number 0000 +(count+ 1)]`
So imagine I choose Camera from the drop down box 
the function will count the total number of Cameras from ``` type`` column in ```sys``` table, display the total + 1
This if there is 9 Cameras exists in the column 
it will give out 10
As the generated code output will be

```
C-0010
```

I wish to know if writing in php function or in JavaScript function will be better and what structure I can use

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh, I wish to know if writing in php function or in JavaScript function will be better and what structure I can use.

Comment: What do you do with this code number, once generated?

Comment: It will be use as an label for the parts, don't worry, all the date inserted will not be removed, even in the future the row is needed to be deleted, it will not drop out from the table but instead labelled as deleted. So, this idea will not leave any bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User JQuery to send post request without loading your page.

```js
$('#type').change(function(){
  console.log('check if working');

  $.post(
    'parts.php',{
      'getPartCode' : $('#type').val()
    },function(data){
      console.log('parts.php result ' + data);

      $('#ivno').val(data);
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <label for="PartType">Part Type</label></br>
  <select name="PartType" id="type">
  <option value="C">Camera</option>
  <option value="L">Lighting</option>
  <option value="X">Lens</option>
  <option value="R">Controller</option>
  <option value="B">Cable</option>
  <option value="S">Scope</option>
  </select>
  </div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
<input type="text" name="RAND" id="ivno" readonly>
</div>
```

In you PHP script

**parts.php**

```
    <?php
   $part_code = '';
   if(isset($_POST['getPartCode'])) {
      #Connect to your database
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inventory_sys");  

      #Use escape string or prepared statement
      $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['getPartCode']);

      $sql = "SELECT CAST(CONCAT('$type-', SUBSTR('0000' , 1, (LENGTH('0000') - LENGTH(CAST(COUNT(1) AS CHAR)))), COUNT(1)) AS CHAR) as partCode FROM sys WHERE type = '$type'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

      echo $row['partCode'];
   }
?>
```

Comment: I've added some my code in for the *parts.php*. I know there's some errors, as I wish to `COUNT` the value of the part selected from the drop down box within `type` column in the `sys` table

Comment: I changed the query to process the Part Code.

Comment: Is it possible if I don't use $_POST ? It is not working cause the page is needed to be refresh in order to get the PartCode, which is not what I want, I wish it to be able to detect the type and run the COUNT then function and display right away. I've added my idea of the JavaScript, is it possible to do so?

Comment: if $_POST is not getting any request then the $.post is not working. try to add console.log before $.post to check if its working. ex: console.log('Working');

Comment: Undefined index: PartType in parts.php on line 5

Comment: change the PartType into getPartCode, I think you initially use the getPartCode and PartType is does not exists in $_POST request

Comment: Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in parts.php on line 5 -0000

Comment: ohh you need to have a valid connection first, move the connect up and add $connect in mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209417/discussion-between-lim-and-gilbertdim).

Comment: Looking at this, I think if two or more users request a part number at the same time, they could be all issued with the same number. You should allocate a part number _after_ the record of that part has been inserted into the database (or more accurately _during_ the insert - by relying on an auto-increment field), not beforehand.